# Scaling QLabel to accommodate the contained text and nothing more

Tags: qt, qlabel

I’m subclassing QLabel and inserting it into a QVBoxLayout and I’m having a problem with the size. The following screenshot is how my application currently looks:

[image]

The yellow widget on the top is my `QLabel`, and the layout is the default one. I’d like my label to scale down to fit the text without manually setting it with `setMinimumHeight()`, however that wouldn’t allow me to use strings longer than the width of the label. I’ve checked the documentation for `QString` (which is what I am passing to the label’s constructor) and I can’t find a way to extract the size of the text. Is there any way I can dynamically change the size of my label to fit the text, with no excess space?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can find out the width of the text through the `QFontMetrics` of the `QLabel`. For example:

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel("Text");
int w = label->fontMetrics().width(label->text());
qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << w;
//in my case this results in 24px, so 6px per character.
```